# Conditional Delete in Apache SOLR

Tags: solr

In Apache solr I have a collection in which need to delete documents based on date column.
I am able to delete all documents for one date using below xml in Request-Handler (qt) of type update:

```
<delete> 
   <query>load_date:"2019-02-14T00:00:00Z"</query> 
</delete>
```

Can we use between clause to pass date range to perform delete of all documents in a date range of say 1st to 15th Feb?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regular range query should work:

```
<delete> 
   <query>load_date:[2019-01-01T00:00:00Z TO 2019-02-15T00:00:00Z]</query> 
</delete>
```

This will include any document with `2019-02-15T00:00:00Z` as it date as well. Use  `}` instead of `]` if you want to exclude any documents with `load_date` set to the 15th.